# How to find owl carousel data attribute?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I want to get owl carousel data attribute item number. The code below does not work for me. Can any one help me?

```
$('.myOwl').on('click', '.owl-item', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = $(this).data("owlCarousel"); alert(number);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: show html too please .. maybe put item-number instead of owlCarousel

Comment: hi @medda86, Thank you very much, can you please answer for this question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040649/what-is-the-owlitem-in-owl-carousel

Comment: What is the `.data("owlItem")`

Answer (score 0):

In version v1.3.2 try

```
 jQuery('#owl-demo').data('owlCarousel').itemsAmount
```

or to get a list off all the properties

```
jQuery('#owl-demo').data('owlCarousel')
```