# What is the owlItem in owl carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

Any one have idea about this

> .data("owlItem")

? how can i find this on jquery or console log. i think this is not data attribute.

**.data("owlItem")**

```
.data("owlItem")


$("#slider_thumb").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){      
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).data("owlItem"); 
    sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please check this. http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html

Comment: There is `$(this).data("owlItem");`. just wanted to know what is that? how can i get value for that

Comment: did my answer not work?

Answer (score -1):

```
var number = $(this).find(".item h1").html();
alert(number);
```